# How to remove values from Specific Dictionary Key Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I suppose I have a dict.

```
D1 = {'B1': [3, 3], 'C1' : [4, 5]}
```

I wanted to remove the value **4** from key **C1**.

So the Output:

```
D1 = {'B1': [3, 3], 'C1' : [ 5]}
```

.

I searched online, but most of the results show how to delete a key from a dict or how do delete all certain type of values from all keys (such as all the 3's from a dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
D1["C1"].remove(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't trying to do anything to a key; you are just trying to remove a value from an array, which happens to be in a dictionary.  So, as others have said, you use the `remove` method of that array.

Comment: Thank you sir for the good explanation ! That put things in good prespective